# is it possible to use dropbox datastore api as shared datastore?

Tags: dropbox-api

I need to develop a simple app which must save items. 
I would like to use dropbox datastore api to allow cross device sync
Also I need five users to share the same data
Must I use a DB server or can I allow an user to share its cloud saved data with other users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropbox Datastore API will automatically sync datastores across devices running an app linked to the same account.

The Dropbox Datastore API also offers the ability to share datastores across accounts. For more information on how your app can share datastores, check out the tutorial here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/ios#sharing-a-datastore